Transcendental Relations in the Trinity
According to Dom Reginald Garrigou Lagrange: “Real relations are divided into transcendental and predicamental. A transcendental relation is the order included in the essence of a thing as, for example, the soul’s transcendental order to the body, that of matter to form, essence to being, accident to the subject, science to its object, etc. All these things have these relations by their very essence, and the transcendental relation perdures even when the term disappears” (The Trinity and God the Creator 2:28). With this said, are the personal relations in the Blessed Trinity transcendental relations as defined by Dom Reginald Garrigou-Lagrange?

The personal relations in the Trinity differ even from Lagrange's transcendental relations because Trinitary relations do not imply a division even between essence and existence at all unlike those of either predicamental or transcendental. The relations of origin here are supposed to be pure relationality without implying any division within the divine simplicity and unity. This unique relational reality of the Trinity is what theologians like Aquinas call subsistent relations or relations of opposition that do not alter the divine simplicity and unity.

This seems a better question for a Christianity stack than for the philosophy stack...

I have VTC because questions about Christian orthodoxy are better fit for Christianity SE.

I’m voting to close this question because Chistianity SE is a far better site for theological material of this detail orientation.
